# Transform an array of shape (n,) to a numpy array of shape (n,1)

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array that I read from a `.npz` file with numpy, that has a shape I can not really explain.

When I print the array I get numbers in the following form:

```
[1 2 3 2 1 8 9 8 3 4 ...]
```

without any comma separating them

I would like to transform this array into a numpy array of dimensions `(n,1)` where n is the number of elements and 1 is the number of columns.

Is there an elegant way of doing it?

Comment: The lack of commas is not significant.  That's just how `numpy` prints arrays (with the `str` formatting).  Use `repr` formatting if you want to see commas.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The shape `(n, )` means its a one-dimensional array of `n` length . If you think the shape `(n, 1)` represents a one-dimensional array, then it does not, `(n,1)` represents a two dimensional array of n sub-arrays, with each sub-array having 1 element.

If what you really want is an array of shape `(n, 1)`, you can use `ndarray.reshape()` with shape `(-1, 1)` -

```
array.reshape((-1,1))
```

Demo -

```
In [64]: na
Out[64]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [65]: str(na)
Out[65]: '[0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9]'

In [66]: na.reshape((-1,1))
Out[66]:
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])

In [67]: na.reshape((-1,1)).shape
Out[67]: (10, 1)
```

As you can see this moves the array from being a 1d array to a 2d array with each inner row (inner array) containing only 1 element. This may not be what you want. The output like -

```
[1 2 3 2 1 8 9 8 3 4 ...]
```

is just the `str()` result of a numpy array, it does mean the elements internally are not separated.